# Swaping camera in between video conference using WebRTC

Tags: html, webrtc

Is it possible to swap the camera in during a video call on mobile?
I can get the available cameras using `MediaStreamTrack.getSources()`.
But I'm able to swap them mid-call.

Any ideas on how to swap during a video call using html and javascript (I'm developing a hybrid app).

Also: is it possible to make Safari (iOS) compatible for webRTC without any plugin?

Comment: For that last question: No. Safari doesn't support WebRTC, period. Only a native plugin can change that, there's no Javascript shim for that or similar.

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas on how to swap during a video call using html and javascript.

Something like this should work in Chrome*:

```
function switchCamera() {
  // get new stream (different camera)
  getUserMedia(constraints, function(newStream){
    var oldStream = peerConnection.getLocalStreams()[0];

    // toggle streams
    peerConnection.removeStream(oldStream);
    peerConnection.addStream(newStream);

    // re-negotiate
    peerConnection.createOffer(function (offer) {
      peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
      // sendOfferToPeers(offer);
    });
  }, function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  })
}


function gotOffer(offer) {
  peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(offer);
  peerConnection.createAnswer(function(answer) {
    peerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);
    // sendAnswerToPeers(answer);
  });
}

function gotAnswer(answer) {
  peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(answer);
}
```

*you mentioned something about being on mobile so the way you obtain the stream might be different. **Also I didn't test this code and the API looks different, have a look [here for the correct function calls createAnswer etc.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection)**. But the gist of it should be the same:

1. Acquire new stream
2. Update peerConnection
3. Inform peers (re-negotiate)

> Also: is it possible to make Safari (iOS) compatible for webRTC without any plugin?

No. You can have a [look here for updates.](http://iswebrtcreadyyet.com/)